# Calculation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to get Break Even Point **(BEP)** and selling value using jquery.

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
}

$("#cost").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  var cost = Number($('#cost').val());
  var text
  var total_cost = roundToTwo(((cost * 18) / 100) + cost);

  var profit = -0.5;
  var sell = cost + 0.01;
  while (profit <= 0) {

    sell = sell + 0.01;
    profit = roundToTwo(sell - total_cost);


    text += "<br />New Sell " + sell + " and profit " + profit;
  }
  var bep = roundToTwo(sell - total_cost);
  $('#bep_display').text(bep);
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = text;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" placeholder="cost" name="cost">
<h1 id="bep_display">

</h1>
<p id="testing"></p>
```

Now by running the above code, I entered **1** in the input, so the result (BEP) should be **0**, but it gives **`NaN`**

Comment: This seems to be because for broken floating numbers in javascript

Comment: @MaheerAli So, what's the alternative method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your answer returns with `e`  so it shows `NaN`. Try:

```
var bep = parseFloat(sell - total_cost).toFixed(8);
```

This will give you the result **0.00000000**.

If you need a result as **0**. Add:

```
bep = roundToTwo(bep);
```

```js
function roundToTwo(num) {
  return +(Math.round(num + "e+2") + "e-2");
}

$("#cost").on("change keyup paste", function() {
  var cost = Number($('#cost').val());
  var text
  var total_cost = roundToTwo(((cost * 18) / 100) + cost);

  var profit = -0.5;
  var sell = cost + 0.01;
  while (profit <= 0) {

    sell = sell + 0.01;
    profit = roundToTwo(sell - total_cost);


    text += "<br />New Sell " + sell + " and profit " + profit;
  }
  var bep = parseFloat(sell - total_cost).toFixed(8);
  bep = roundToTwo(bep);
  $('#bep_display').text(bep);
  document.getElementById("testing").innerHTML = text;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="cost" placeholder="cost" name="cost">
<h1 id="bep_display">

</h1>
<p id="testing"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line :

```
var bep = roundToTwo(sell - total_cost);
```

One solution is to fixed your decimals, for example :

```
var bep = roundToTwo(sell.toFixed(8) - total_cost.toFixed(8));
```

Comment: it means your decimal will fixed to 8, like ; 3.20348374 you can change it as you wish, if you say .toFixed(4) then you have only 4 decimals points like : 4.8765